# Adding parameters to the UpdateMethod of an ObjectDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, webforms, objectdatasource

Ok, so I am working with ASP WebForms and have a ListView (for account customers) inside another ListView (for accounts).

This inner ListView has an ObjectDataSource for the account customers (referred to as participants in this particular application).

Here it is:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="dataSourceParticipants" runat="server" 
SelectMethod="GetParticipantsForAccount"
UpdateMethod="UpdateParticipantDetails"
DeleteMethod="DeleteParticipantDetails"
InsertMethod="InsertParticipantDetails"
TypeName="PreScreening2.AccountManagerWrapper"
DataObjectTypeName="PreScreening2.BLL.Models.Participant">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="grdAccounts" Name="accountNumber" PropertyName="SelectedDataKey.Values[AccountNumber]"
            Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

And here is my AccountManagerWrapper class (poorly named):

```
public class AccountManagerWrapper
{
    [Inject]
    public IAccountManager AccountManager { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    public IParticipantManager ParticipantManager { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Participant> GetParticipantsForAccount(string accountNumber)
    {
        return AccountManager.GetParticipantsForAccount(accountNumber);
    }

    public bool UpdateParticipantDetails(Participant participant)
    {
        return ParticipantManager.UpdateParticipantDetails(participant, null, AccountManager);
    }

    public bool DeleteParticipantDetails(Participant participant)
    {
        return ParticipantManager.DeleteParticipant(participant, null, AccountManager);
    }

    public bool InsertParticipantDetails(Participant participant)
    {
        return ParticipantManager.UpdateParticipantDetails(participant, null, AccountManager);
    }
}
```

On the **ItemDataBound** event of my outer ListView, I am doing this:

```
protected void grdAccounts_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        var dataItem = e.Item as ListViewDataItem;
        if (dataItem != null)
        {
            var parentID = ((BLL.Models.Account)dataItem.DataItem).AccountNumber;

            var sqlParts = (ObjectDataSource)e.Item.FindControl("dataSourceParticipants");

            if (sqlParts != null)
            {
                var parameterParentID = sqlParts.SelectParameters[0];
                parameterParentID.DefaultValue = parentID;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly, it's important to clarify that everything above this line works 100%, all of the methods do exactly what I want them to do.

I want to update my **UpdateParticipantDetails** method like so:

```
    public bool UpdateParticipantDetails(Participant participant, string accountNumber)
    {
        return ParticipantManager.UpdateParticipantDetails(participant, accountNumber, AccountManager);
    }
```

I want to pass the same **AccountNumber** property into this method that I am using as the **PropertyName** for the **ControlParameter** in **SelectParameters** above.

What do I need to add to the HTML of **dataSourceParticipants** to pass this new value into my Update method?

I have tried this:

```
<UpdateParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="grdAccounts" Name="participant"/>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="grdAccounts" Name="accountNumber" PropertyName="SelectedDataKey.Values[AccountNumber]" Type="String"/>
</UpdateParameters>
```

Resharper gives me this error:

> Incorrect number of parameters

And when I try to update, I get the following execution time error:

> ObjectDataSource 'dataSourceParticipants' could not find a non-generic method 'UpdateParticipantDetails' that takes parameters of type 'PreScreening2.BLL.Models.Participant'.

Thanks